# LMDB Java retrieve all values with same key

Tags: java, database, lmdb

I want to store multiple values with the same key. I made sure to include the `MDB_DUPSORT` flag when creating the database. I am also aware this limits the value size but in this specific case this is not a problem.

My problem starts when I want to read the values with the same keys. I searched but could not find a clear answer on how to do this.

So basically: how to retrieve all values with the same key?

I use [lmdbjava](https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava) to read/write from the database.

I tried this but the iterator continues on with the next key and does not stop when the last value is read:

```
try(Txn<ByteBuffer> txn = env.txnRead()) {
    CursorIterator<ByteBuffer> cursor = db.iterate(txn, KeyRange.atLeast(key));

    for(CursorIterator.KeyVal<ByteBuffer> kv : cursor.iterable()) {
        ByteBuffer value = kv.val();

        byte[] bytes = new byte[value.remaining()];

        value.get(bytes);

        System.out.println(bytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `KeyRange.atLeast` which according to the javadoc

> starts on the passed key (or the first key immediately after it) and
>   iterate forward until no keys remain

I think you'd want to use `KeyRange.closed`

> Iterate forward between the passed keys, matching on the first keys
>   directly equal to the passed key (or immediately following it in the
>   case of the "start" key, or immediately preceding it in the case of
>   the "stop" key).

Test for it

```
  @Test
  public void dupSortKeyRange() {

    final Dbi<ByteBuffer> db = env.openDbi(DB_1, MDB_CREATE, MDB_DUPSORT);

    try (Txn<ByteBuffer> txn = env.txnWrite()) {
      db.put(txn, bb(5), bb(6));
      db.put(txn, bb(5), bb(7));
      db.put(txn, bb(5), bb(8));
      db.put(txn, bb(6), bb(9));
      txn.commit();
    }

    try (Txn<ByteBuffer> txn = env.txnRead()) {
      ByteBuffer key = bb(5);

      List<Integer> keyValues = new ArrayList<>();
      CursorIterator<ByteBuffer> cursor = db.iterate(txn, KeyRange.closed(key, key));
      for (CursorIterator.KeyVal<ByteBuffer> kv : cursor.iterable()) {
        ByteBuffer value = kv.val().get(new byte[kv.val().remaining()]);
        keyValues.add(value.getInt(0));
      }

      assertEquals(3, keyValues.size(), 0);
      assertTrue(keyValues.containsAll(Arrays.asList(6, 7, 8)));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sean, this is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks!